# JSON con propiedad Map

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo una duda respecto a un JSON que en una propiedad me la devuelve como aparece en la imagen, no se como acceder a esas propiedades ya que tienen una especie de map o no se que sea exactamente, intente acceder a las propiedades como si fueran parte del un arreglo pero no funciono y con la funcion map.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si haces `console.log( JSON.stringify( objeto ) )`, ¿ que te muestra ? Creo que deberías [edit] y añadirlo a la pregunta.

Comment: Un map es justanmente un objeto `JSON`. si quieres acceder a las propiedades de un Map lo harias de la misma forma como lo harias normalmente, es decir mediante el `.`. por ejemplo, en tu caso hay una propiedad llamada `jesus_4Fheaven117`, y para acceder a su valor seria: `elNombreDeTuMap.jesus_5heaven117`, asi estarias accediendo entonces al valor de esa propiedad.

Comment: @Trauma Me muestra un objeto vacio

Comment: @Riven no me deja asi, si te das cuenta son dos campos, el campo 0 y 1

Comment: @ASASCED Por lo que dices, podría ser un [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map). Ignoraba que su deserialización desde JSON fuera ... distinta. Intenta acceder a sus elementos con el método `.get( key )`.

Comment: Ahh si, cierto, se me olvida esa diferencia que hay entre un `Map` y un objeto `JSON`, con el metodo get podras hacerlo, asi como ha dicho trauma.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque se agregan como un arreglo de dos elementos `[elem1, elem2]`, el objeto Map los convertirá en pares de `clave / valor`.

> El [objeto Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map) almacena pares clave/valor. Cualquier valor (tanto objetos como valores primitivos) pueden ser usados como clave o valor.

Como es un objeto iterable, puedes recorrerlo con [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach):

- Recorrer solo valores: `map.forEach(function(valor) { ...código... });`
- Recorrer valores y claves: `map.forEach(function(valor, clave) { ...código... });`

```js
let map = new Map([
    ["jesus_5f", "Jesus Jimenez"],
    ["abc123", "abc123"]
]);
// Agregar elemento
map.set("nueva clave", "nuevo valor");

// Obtener un elemento específico
console.log('Un solo elemento: ' + map.get("jesus_5f"));

// Recorrer el mapa
map.forEach(function(valor, clave) {
    console.log(`${clave} = ${valor}`);
    // Aquí tu código
});

// Ver todo el contenido,  "..." para destructurar y se pueda mostrar
console.log(...map);
```